# Odoo10 access rights

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

I create my own group in odoo hr,supervisor,employee
How can i customize each groups access rights using xml?
For example a hr module

- Hr can access everything
- Supervisor can only access his employee in his or her department
- And employee can only access his own profile

But when im trying to access employee profile using hr group account it gives me an error

```
Model_id not found  missing field 'object'
```

Im still new in odoo hope you can help me

Comment: Post the code..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add model ID in CSV file.
Moreover, you need to set access rules to achieve your feature.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add model ID in CSV file.
Moreover, The feature you want to achieve